# Cannot play (most of) Brightcove player videos

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video

I cannot play any documentary from Aljazeera website (for example, [this one](https://www.aljazeera.com/programmes/rebel-education/2016/12/teaching-empowerment-prison-education-kenya-161216145142193.html). All of these are embedded in a [Brightcove](https://support.brightcove.com/) player (I can play the live stream though, which is also in Brightcove).
I have tested the documentaries in an Ubuntu OS (with Firefox), and in a Windows OS (with Firefox and Chrome). None of these play the documentaries. All of these sessions do pass the [Brightcove HTML5 test](https://sadmin.brightcove.com/html5support/index.html):

[image]

I have tried disabling hardware acceleration, erasing all data (cookies, etc), deactivating adblocker, HTTPS Everywhere and other add ons. Nothing. What is going on?

PS: Notice that I can play the documentaries on my android device.

Comment: I just tested in Ubuntu and it plays.

Comment: "What is going on?" - Use a proxy or a VPN, it is possible, your ISP is doing a bad job of filtering content.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a different video host. Turns out it was being filtered by my firewall for some reason. Whitelisted it and it started working.